# Correct way to write helper functions in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm new to Meteor and I'm trying to figure out the difference between writing:

```
Template.main.folks =
  function () {
    return Clients.find();
};
```

and writing it using "helpers":

```
Template.main.helpers({
  folks: function () {
    return Clients.find();
});
```

Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing difference, but the first one is gonna be removed soon. If you do that, it still run, but will give you the `deprecated` warning